# Can't find FormElement class in JSOUP source or library jar

Tags: java, jsoup

Looking at the API for jsoup I found [FormElement](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/FormElement.html)

This seems great but I could not find it. The source "jsoup-1.7.2-sources.jar" from the [download-section](http://jsoup.org/download) did not seem to include it.

Am I looking in the wrong place? Is there a newer/older version which has this class?

Answer (score 1):

Jsoup 1.7.2 is the current version of Jsoup and as the API documents says, the FormElement class is implemented first in the 1.7.3 version, thus you wont be able to use it.

Take a look at the source for Jsoup to view more about FormElement, [here](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/tree/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes)